# Material-UI Snackbar not showing in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am writing an application using the React / Redux / Thunk / Axios stack and have problems with the following piece of code (its a redux action):

```
export function rangeSelected(value) {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {

        let duration = Math.abs(value.end - value.start) / 3.6e6

        if (duration > 4) {
            dispatch(showErrorSnackbar("Error Message 1."));
            return
        } else if (value.start < new Date()) {
            dispatch(showErrorSnackbar("Error Message 2."));
            return
        }

        const {oidc} = getState();

        return axios.get("http://localhost:8000/booking/resource/available", {
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                Authorization: `Bearer ${oidc.user.access_token}`
            },
            params: {
                start: moment(value.start).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'),
                end: moment(value.end).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
            }
        }).then(({data}) => {
            if (data.length === 0) {
                dispatch(showErrorSnackbar("Error Message 3."));
            } else {
                dispatch(openDialogue({
                    resources: data,
                    start: value.start,
                    end: value.end
                }))
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`showErrorSnackbar` is another action just dispatching the following action, which modifies the store and is used to display the message:

```
export const showErrorSnackbar = message => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: SNACKBAR_SHOW, payload: {
                message: message,
                severity: "error"
            }});
    };
};
```

The idea is that I want to run some pre-checks and stop the request / display an error message if they're not met. Then I'm sending the request to my backend API and depending on the response I either dispatch a success action or show another error message (message 3).

The problem now is that message 1 and 2 do not show up in Firefox, but work as expected in Safari. To be precise - the action to show them is dispatched, but immediately afterwards closed again. Looking at the dev toolbar, the `handleClose()` function of the component is called. The stack trace shows, that it's called by:

`handleClickAway` - node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/Snackbar/Snackbar.js:187

Message 3 is displayed perfectly fine and so are all three messages in Safari.

// For reference //

This is the Snackbar Component:

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import Snackbar from "@material-ui/core/Snackbar";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import {Icon} from "@material-ui/core";
import {clearSnackbar} from "../../redux/actions";
import Alert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";

export default function SuccessSnackbar() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const {snackbarMessage, snackbarOpen, snackbarSeverity} = useSelector(
        state => state.ui
    );

    function handleClose() {
        dispatch(clearSnackbar());
    }

    return (
        <Snackbar
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: "bottom",
                horizontal: "left"
            }}
            open={snackbarOpen}
            autoHideDuration={5000}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-describedby="client-snackbar"
            action={[
                <IconButton key="close" aria-label="close" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose}>
                    <Icon>close</Icon>
                </IconButton>
            ]}
        >
            <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity={snackbarSeverity}>
                {snackbarMessage}
            </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
    );
}
```

And this is the reducer:

```
import {SNACKBAR_CLEAR, SNACKBAR_SHOW} from "../types";

const initialState = {
    snackbarMessage: "",
    snackbarOpen: false,
    snackbarSeverity: "success"
};

const uiReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SNACKBAR_SHOW:
            return {
                ...state,
                snackbarOpen: true,
                snackbarMessage: action.payload.message,
                snackbarSeverity: action.payload.severity
            };
        case SNACKBAR_CLEAR:
            return {
                ...state,
                snackbarOpen: false
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default uiReducer;
```

Comment: I suggest to help others help you by creating a full project with only the minimal needed parts to reproduce the problem and share it here. This way we can test and debug locally. You can even create a CodePen/jsFiddle/CodeSandbox with everything in there, so we don't need to handle with it locally.

Comment: @emi will try to do so tomorrow, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The `Snackbar` components has it's own closing mechanism. The `Alert` mechanism used here, should not have any closing component, as you only want it to colorize your message. The closing mechanism is already handled by the `Snackbar`.

Solution: remove `onClose={handleClose}` from the rendered `Alert` component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was not the problem however. I've removed the `onClose` from `Alert` but the result is still the same in both browsers.